# Matching values from multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php

I have a mutidimentional array.

First array:

```
$product_array = array(
    [0] => array(
            [product_id] => 1
         ),
    [1] => array(
            [product_id] => 2
         ),
   [2] => array(
            [product_id] => 3
         ) 
);
```

Second array:

```
$product_id = array(
          '1',
          '3'
     );
```

I want to match all data from `$product_array` with `product_id` key, if `product_id` is found that time return result from `$product_array`.

Expected output:

```
 array(
        [0] => array(
                [product_id] => 1
             ),
       [2] => array(
                [product_id] => 3
             ) 
    );
```

Want to use only one foreach loop.

Is it possible?

Comment: *"Want to use only one foreach loop"* why? Also, this is not a code writing service. Have you tried doing it on your own? And if yes, where did you get stuck? Please, update your question with this information.

Comment: _“Want to use only one foreach loop. Is it possible?”_ - sure - if you use in_array inside to perform the actual check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

```
$matching_array = array_filter($product_array,function($val) use($product_id){
    return in_array($val['product_id'],$product_id);
});
print_r($matching_array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
     (
         [product_id] => 1
     )

 [2] => Array
     (
         [product_id] => 3
     )
 )
```

Comment: It'd be a lot cleaner to pass `$product_id` in with a `use()` statement, rather than using a global.

Answer (score 0):

No loops at all is needed.
Use array_intersect and array_filter.

```
$id = array_column($product_array, "product_id", null);


$match = array_intersect($id, $product_id);
$res = array_filter(
    $product_array,
    function ($key) use ($match) {
        return !in_array($key, $match);
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);


Var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/sLXsu

Comment: Seriously, what's the purpose of redundant `array_column`? Answer below provides the same without any additional arrays and function calls.

Comment: Didn't think about that...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and quickest solution, using `foreach` as you want is:

```
foreach( $product_array as $key => $value ){
    $prid = $value['product_id'];
    if( !in_array( $prid , $product_id ) ) unset( $product_array[$key] );
}
```